# Pipenv incorrectly creating Pipfile in user's home directory

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

I want to make a project and virtualenv in `/users/me/my-project`
In the past, when I've done this I:

1. `cd` into the project folder, here `my-project`
2. run `pipenv shell` to create do the setup and start interactive session
3. run `pipenv install` to install the packages I want.

In the past, this has worked fine - the pipfile exists in the project director and virtualenv is mapped correctly. For some reason, now it is making the Pipfile in the parent directory, `/users/me/`. I've also tried doing pipenv in a sub directory in my project, and it still creates it in the home directory as before.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hey @Peter, did you manage to figure out why this is happening? running into the same issue.

Comment: Nope! I took the nuclear option and deleted everything in `local/share/virtualenvs` in frustration. That fixed it but I haven't any idea why.

Comment: ahhhh. thanks! in any case, i uninstalled and re-installed again and it seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing, and I don't know what caused this.  But I found a workaround: Create an empty Pipfile in the directory of choice:

```
% cd <project_directory>
% touch Pipfile
% pipenv --python 3.10
```

To be honest I needed to do a bit more fussing about, including `pipenv --rm` at least once.  But then it started working.  Hope this helps someone (and please refine this answer)!